# from underscore template to mustache.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, mustache

I would like to change from `underscore template` to `mustache.js`.

Since in mustache.js there are no `if statements` how can I change this piece of code in order to use `mustache.js` ?

```
<% if (done) { %>
<span class="todo-clear">
    <a href="#">
    Clear <span class="number-done"><%= done %></span>
    completed <span class="word-done"><%= done === 1 ? 'item' : 'items' %></span>
    </a>
</span>
<% } %>
```

My solution is:

```
 {{#total}}
        <span class="todo-count">{{ total }}
          <span class="number">{{ remaining }}</span>
          <span class="word"><%= remaining == 1 ? 'item' : 'items' %></span> left.-->
        </span>
          <span class="hint">
          Drag tasks from one list into another and vice versa.
          </span>
 {{/total}}
```

It works for total  variable, because it could be 0 or more, but I have no idea what is the best way to fix it on remaining variable, which could be 1 or more.

```
<span class="word"><%= remaining == 1 ? 'item' : 'items' %></span> left.</span>
```

It should be something like that:

```
<span class="word">
    {{#remaining}} 'items'  {{/remaining}} 
    {{^remaining}} 'item'  {{/remaining}}
</span>
```

It does not work because remaining could be 1 or more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view you could make something like this:

```
Mustache.render(yourTemplate, {
     remaining: items.length > 1 ? true : false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your just moving to a new templating framework, I would recommend using [handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/). This has support for if statements as follows:

```
{{#if total}}
  <span>something</span>
{{else}}
  <span>something else</span>
{{/if}}
```

Comment: According to the `Handlebars` documentation `if statements` works in this way: If its argument returns false, undefined, null or [] (a "falsy" value), `Handlebars` will not render the block. But this is equivalent to make `{{#total}}` and `{{^total}}` in mustache.